# Android built-in SIP library doesn't end a call correctly?

Tags: java, android, sip, voip, asterisk

I used the Android built-in sip library to write an app that makes calls via my own Asterisk server. The calls are being made correctly, but most of the time, the calls aren't ended correctly.

This is my code to end the call:

```
public void stopCalling(){
    try {
        call.endCall();
        call.close();
    } catch (SipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Could someone explain to me why the calls are sometimes ended correctly, but most of the time not?

To give you an example of what happens, when I call from my android phone to a sip client on a pc, it rings. when I call the stopCalling method from the android device, the pc client keeps ringing, when I pick up the call on the pc, there just isn't any sound and eventually, the connection times out and the call is ended on the pc client side. When I end the call after the pc client picks up, the audio stream is stopped immediately, but the call is not ended until the connection times out.

Comment: Sounds more like a packet routing problem to me. You should describe your setup (network). Where's your Android, where's your asterisk running, where's your PC SIP client, which routers are involved, how are the relevant firewalls configured. -- Setup is one thing, but some routers fail to deal with small scenarios altogether, being only capable of handling "real" setups (no incoming and outgoing call simultaneously, asterisk server cannot be local under certain conditions, etc...)

Comment: Well, since this is an "exercise" for my internship, I don't really have access to routers and I have no idea about the network setup. But sometimes the BYE packet is sent perfectly fine, sometimes not. Is there some way to find out if this is an asterisk problem or an android problem? How would I find out?

Comment: Everything is running on a local network.

Comment: I don't think it's an asterisk or an Android problem, I think it's a network setup problem. As I said, please describe where in the network your two SIP clients and your asterisk are located. Please note that your problem is not that the call isn't ended correctly. Your problem is that you don't hear anything. Depending on your specific test setup, involving a STUN server could help, but maybe not. Most likely, one of the involved firewalls is causing the trouble -- could be your PC's, could be the router's, I don't know and I even can't guess because you don't describe your setup.

Comment: "a local network" is not sufficient information. Is it the same network segment, or is a router involved?

Comment: What do you mean by "the problem is that you don't hear anything?", the audio is working fine, I can make calls without a problem. It's just that when I end the call, only the audio stream stops, but the call keeps going on. As for the setup, I have a laptop that runs asterisk, I have a laptop that has an SIP client and I have an android phone with my test application, they're all on the same local network subnet. Since the BYE packets are sometimes being sent and received just fine, I don't think they're being blocked by the router, because then they would never be received.

Comment: Okay then I got the following wrong: _"when I pick up the call on the pc, there just isn't any sound"_ but now I understand that you meant it in the context of a call which had already been terminated. -- If I were in your shoes, I'd first use wireshark and see whether that `BYE` packet is actually sent or not. And I'd try different Android versions if possible.